# How to select first row then other rows from a single mysql query?

Tags: php, mysql

I may be missing the obvious, how could I return the results I need? Take a look at this simple example:

```
$fetch_image = "SELECT image_url FROM table"; //returns about 10 rows
$stmt_img = $db->prepare($fetch_image);
$stmt_img->execute();
$stmt_img_result = $stmt_img->get_result();

while ($row_img = $stmt_img_result->fetch_assoc()) {
     $image = $row_image['image_url'];
     echo 'Image url: '.$image.'<br>'; //this will echo out 10 times.
}
```

The above code iterates through all 10 rows. How could I return the first row from the result set, and then the other 9 rows?

Edit: I'm trying to create an image previewer so that the first image shows up as the placeholder/main image then the other 9 rows show up as the thumbnails, something like this:

```
<div class="sp-wrap">
            <a href="images/1.jpg">
                <!-- This would be the placeholder/main/first image from the mysql result set -->
                <img src="images/1_tb.jpg" alt="">
            </a>
            <!-- In real life these would be dynamically generated -->
            <a href="images/3.jpg"><img src="images/3_tb.jpg" alt=""></a>
            <a href="images/4.jpg"><img src="images/4_tb.jpg" alt=""></a>
            <a href="images/5.jpg"><img src="images/5_tb.jpg" alt=""></a>
            <a href="images/6.jpg"><img src="images/6_tb.jpg" alt=""></a>
        </div>
```

Comment: make imageType Column in your table then use this query

SELECT image_url FROM table order by imageType

Comment: Aside from the SQL query, I'd like to know how to do it in the result set i.e. the while loop

Comment: save imageType values in your database 1 for the first image you want to make appear

Comment: A simple boolean $first_row, initially set to true, then checked within the loop would do the job.

Comment: If the DOM is the same from row to row, but only the "styling" (image dimensions) changes, couldn't you just leave all of the work to css?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/g78h0tz3/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple boolean variable can distinguish the first row:

```
$first_row = true;

while ($row_img = $stmt_img_result->fetch_assoc()) {
     if ($first_row) {
         echo 'the first row';
         $image = $row_image['image_url'];
         echo 'Image url: '.$image.'<br>';
         $first_row = false;
     } else {
         $image = $row_image['image_url'];
         echo 'Image url: '.$image.'<br>'; //this will echo out 9 times.
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You may try to get the first row, and then the rest. But you need an `ORDER BY` clause in your SQL statement that will order rows in the same way in every execution.

```
<?php
$fetch_image = "SELECT image_url FROM table"; //returns about 10 rows
$stmt_img = $db->prepare($fetch_image);
$stmt_img->execute();
$stmt_img_result = $stmt_img->get_result();

// Fetch first row
if ($row_first = $stmt_img_result->fetch_assoc()) {
     $image = $row_first['image_url'];
     echo 'Image url: '.$image.'<br>'; 
}

// Fetch next rows
while ($row_next = $stmt_img_result->fetch_assoc()) {
     $image = $row_next['image_url'];
     echo 'Image url: '.$image.'<br>'; 
}
?>
```

Another possible approach is to implement custom check for first row:

```
<?php
$fetch_image = "SELECT image_url FROM table"; //returns about 10 rows
$stmt_img = $db->prepare($fetch_image);
$stmt_img->execute();
$stmt_img_result = $stmt_img->get_result();

$first = true;
while ($row_img = $stmt_img_result->fetch_assoc()) {
   if ($first) {
      // Specific output for the first row
      $first = false;
      $image = $row_image['image_url'];
      echo 'Image url: '.$image.'<br>'; // this will echo out 1 time.
   } else {
      // Specific output for the next rows
      $image = $row_image['image_url'];
      echo 'Image url: '.$image.'<br>'; // this will echo out count - 1 times.
   }
}
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

make `imageType Column` in your table then use this query

```
SELECT image_url FROM table order by imageType`
```

give value 1 to the image you want to appear first in the loop.

if your first row is having the first image then you don't need imageType column. you can simply use

```
SELECT image_url FROM table order by id
```

> where id is you PRIMARY KEY

but still, the above method is a more dynamic approach in case your records will change in the future. it is better to give them imageType column for future use which is more proper way instead of just getting the first record from the database.

```
    $stmt_img = $db->prepare($fetch_image);
    $stmt_img->execute();
    $stmt_img_result = $stmt_img->get_result();

  if ( $firstrow = mysql_fetch_assoc($stmt_img_result) ) {
        $image = $firstrow['image_url'];
         echo 'Image url: '.$image.'<br>'; //this will echo out 1 times.

    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($stmt_img_result)) {


      $image = $row['image_url'];
         echo 'Image url: '.$image.'<br>'; //this will echo out 9 times.

      }

    }
```

Comment: This may work but it still does require an unnecessary column to the database when it could just as well be done with PHP. (but I didn't downvote)

Comment: @BillWhickomb thanks for telling me. What I have learned on StackOverflow so far is to telling OPs the proper way how to do things instead of just giving them a solution to their problem. It is a proper even if it adds up an extra column in the database, it is what he will require in the future. and I also given another solution without adding extra column, i.e order by primary key

Comment: I don't find this to be the "proper" way to do this task.  If I were doing this task for work, I'd probably go for Zhorov's first code block because it isn't performing any wasted conditional checks inside of a loop.

Comment: @mickmackusa what if his record from where he is getting admin image is changed in the future or get deleted?

Comment: I don't see how that is a concern.  The OP wants to do something with the first row, then something different for all subsequent rows.  No reason to invent fringe cases here.

Comment: @mickmackusa check it out I gave a solution but I was told by most of the others that we should tell OPs a proper way instead of just providing them solution to their problem 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55037320/how-to-perform-select-operation-in-between-comma-seperated-input-string-and-comm

Comment: Yes, I agree. We should always tell the OP the "proper" way.  I just don't agree that your answer is the "proper" way.  There is unnecessary overhead with your suggestion.  Zhorov's solution has no unnecesssary overhead.

Comment: @mickmackusa I already told why I said it is a more proper approach but you said don't invent fringe cases here.

Comment: @mickmackusa Ok, I am editing my answer I just need to add the PHP part also.

Comment: `$img_rows = $stmt_img_result->fetch_assoc();` would be better named `$img_row` since you are only fetching a single row from the result set.  I expect that your edited snippet will not work as desired.